# How to copy R1C1 formula in a range of cells in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy R1C1 formula to a range of cells. But I am getting error Run time 1004.

Following is the code:

```
Dim cell_range As String
cell_range = "E126:E146"
Formula = Application.ConvertFormula( _
                                    Formula:=Formula, _
                                    fromReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, _
                                    toReferenceStyle:=xlA1)
wk_sht.range(cell_range).FormulaR1C1 = Formula
```

Original Formula is :

```
=IF(C126="","",IF(SIZE_CHECK=TRUE,IF('Sheet1'!L14<>"",'Sheet2'!M14,"TBA"),""))
```

Formula after converting to R1C1 is:

```
=IF($DV:$DV="","",IF(SIZE_CHECK=TRUE,IF('[Excel.xlsm]Sheet1'!'L14'<>"",'[Excel.xlsm]Sheet2'!'M14',"TBA"),""))
```

using this line of code:

```
Formula = Application.ConvertFormula( _
                                    Formula:=Formula, _
                                    fromReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, _
                                    toReferenceStyle:=xlA1)
```

Comment: What's the error and what's the formula?

Comment: Can you please check I have converted formula to R1C1 using this statement 
Formula = Application.ConvertFormula( _
                                    Formula:=Formula, _
                                    fromReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, _
                                    toReferenceStyle:=xlA1)

Comment: It's not even a valid A1 formula at all, you shouldn't have single quotes around the range references. Is this the formula you are trying to use in the code or are you trying to convert it to R1C1 notation and use the result in the code?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to copy formula from cell and convert it to R1C1 and pasting it to another workbook in the range of cells. I have edited my question again with detailed formula please see. Thanks

Comment: You actually appear to be converting from R1C1 to A1 but the original R1C1 formula is not valid - L14 and M14 aren't valid R1C1 references, and that's why they appear within single quotes in the A1 version of the formula.

Comment: How can I convert to R1C1 then ?

Comment: If you already have a complete A1 formula in a string, there is zero need to convert it to R1C1. Just assign it to `.Formula` instead of `.FormulaR1C1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is the formula you want to convert to R1C1,

```
=IF(C126="","",IF(SIZE_CHECK=TRUE,IF('Sheet1'!L14<>"",'Sheet2'!M14,"TBA"),""))
```

try this code.

Change `Sheets("Sheet1")` to refer to the sheet you want the formula to go on.

```
Sub InsertFormula()
Dim wk_sht As Worksheet
Dim cell_range As String
Dim strFormulaA1 As String
Dim strFormulaR1C1 As String

    Set wk_sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    cell_range = "E126:E146"
    
    strFormulaA1 = "=IF(C126="""","""",IF(SIZE_CHECK=TRUE,IF('Sheet1'!L14<>"""",'Sheet2'!M14,""TBA""),""""))"
    
    strFormulaR1C1 = Application.ConvertFormula( _
                                    Formula:=strFormulaA1, _
                                    fromReferenceStyle:=xlA1, _
                                    toReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
                                    
    wk_sht.Range(cell_range).FormulaR1C1 = strFormulaR1C1
    
End Sub
```

Comment: R1C1 is convenient when you generate the formula on demand. If you already have a complete A1 formula, there is no need to convert it to R1C1. `wk_sht.Range(cell_range).Formula = strFormulaA1`.